# UIWebView goBack to the original position on last page

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari

UIWebView How to archive that invoke “goBack"can actually back to the original position on last page like safari’s back/forward function.

Comment: web view has a scrollView property, scrollView has a contentOffset property that you can get or set.  web view also has a delegate that tells you about page navigation.  can you take it from there?

Comment: @danh I tried this way.When the page loads is completed,I set the scrollView.contentOffset property but the transition effect is ideal.The page will see page flash process.